# Cascade DIVs like Windows

Tags: javascript, window, draggable, cascade

I'm looking for some JavaScript plugin or lib that can cascade my draggable divs like windows. I've been looking for a while, but haven't found it yet.

Comment: What kind of divs do you have? What about your CSS? May be jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you trying to recreate a windows desktop with JS & CSS? [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=windows%207%20css)

Answer (score 0):

Would you want something like this? https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: not exactly. Imagine a Windows 7 Desktop with multiple open windows. I need some plugin that can arrange this windows in cascade and/or tiles.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for what? that? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Your question needs to be more detailed.